# Unable to execute word document containing python code via cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a simple hello world text document named "hello.py" stored in a directory in a drive. I then opened cmd, navigated to the directory where the document was stored, and typed in

```
py hello.py
```

And then cmd gives me this error:

> C:\Users\nufil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: can't open file 'D:\Python\hello.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

How do I rectify this error and make cmd run my code?

Comment: What is the result of `dir` when you are in the directory you navigated to?

Comment: that error is telling you that there is no such file or directory named `hello.py` in the `D:\Python\` folder. Make sure that you are in the right folder before running the command `py hello.py`.

Comment: @blackbrandt This is what I get: 12-07-2021  17:21    <DIR>          .
12-07-2021  17:21    <DIR>          ..
12-07-2021  17:16                20 hello.py.txt
               1 File(s)             20 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  785,934,127,104 bytes free

Comment: Note your hello.py file has an appended hello.py.txt extension.